# Change Jquery Chosen Plugin display font

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".chosen").chosen();
});
</script>


<select class="chosen" style="font-family:arial">
<option>Classification</option>
<option>aaaa</option>
<option>bbb</option>
</select>
```

How can i change Chosen Plugin display font?

I try to change select `style=font-family: Arial` but it's not working,

I also try to change `font-family` inside of chosen.css , it's also not working too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in your css file

```
 .chosen {font-family: Arial !important; }
```

or try

```
<select class="chosen" style="font-family:Arial !important;">
```

Comment: actually i find the solution, i add font-family in 
.chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
&
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {

Comment: hmm !! it was getting overidden by the jquery classes getting added to it

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to set the font size or font family for the result-list you can solved this by adding a jquery call after you create the chosen component.

```
$(".chosen").chosen();
$(".chosen-results").css('font-size','10px');
```

or to change a specific control by id (myspecificchosen),

```
<select class="chosen" id="myspecificchosen" style="width:200px;">
...
$("#myspecificchosen_chosen .chosen-results").css('font-size','10px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwe5r63r/